# I need to remove only one of a duplicate character in my file names - UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, sed

So I have a bunch of file names like `Zubko_141_i00_sed.dat` and `Zubko_135_i00_sed.dat`. My goal here is to get rid of only one of the zeros, and completely replace the filename, so I end up with new filenames like: `Zubko_141_i0_sed.dat`. Is there a quick way to do this with `sed` or another regex command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ var="Zubko_141_i00_sed.dat"
$ echo "${var/00/0}"
Zubko_141_i0_sed.dat
```

With sed it'd be:

```
$ echo "$var" | sed 's/00/0/'
Zubko_141_i0_sed.dat
```

but it's hard to believe you couldn't figure that out so I'm guessing you actually need something else - if so edit your question to clarify.

Given your updated question and comment below, maybe you want:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file/00/0}"; done
```

Comment: Well I need to completely replace the filename of about 330 files named similarly to that, so setting each one equal to a variable would prove to be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

**file.txt:**

```
Zubko_141_i00_sed.dat
Zubko_135_i00_sed.dat
```

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/_i00_/_i0_/' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
Zubko_141_i0_sed.dat
Zubko_135_i0_sed.dat
```